# Access Safari history in `~/Library/` bypassing SIP

Tags: macos, security, permission, sip

I have a Python script which reads the Safari browser history by opening `~/Library/Safari/History.db` and parsing the SQLite database.

Unfortunately, on some Macs, the System Integrity Protection [restricts](https://blog.macsales.com/45473-we-explain-what-system-integrity-protection-on-mac-is-and-how-to-control-it) access to the `~/Library/` directory. It gives a **Operation not permitted** error. Users can manually go to this directory and copy the `History.db` file to the Desktop, and get full access to the database. But is there a way to access `~/Library/Safari/History.db` using only Python or Shell scripts and without the user having to disable SIP, reboot or change any complicated configuration?

Comment: Thanks - I've editted my question to make more obvious why it's not a duplicate. I am hoping to find a user-friendly way to make this work, such that my scripts/app will function on all Macs without much trouble for the user. (It seems this simply is not possible... but you never know until you ask).

Comment: I have SIP enabled and no problem accessing the history file. How are you trying to access it?

Comment: SIP (= 'rootless') is kinda weird. It'll let you access files via Finder (opening, copying etc.) but not via Shell or other scripts (at least, sometimes). So user-mouse movements are okay, but automated code is not. I think starting OS 10.11.

Comment: I don't know how to reliably reproduce the error, but try `cp ~/Library/Safari/History.db ~/Desktop/History.db`. It worked on my Mac but not my colleague's.

Comment: Works without problems. What does `ls -Oe ~/Library/Safari/History.db ~/Desktop/History.db` return on your colleague's Mac? (PS: Please use @nohilside when replying so I get notified)

Comment: I also can run `sqlite3` on the file in place without issues.

Comment: And also ask your colleague whether he got Full Disk Access enabled for Terminal (and check whether you did). My guess it that the error they see comes from them not having enabled it.

Comment: Based on what we know so far this is indeed a duplicate. To have it reopened you may need to show that you get the error message even wit Full Disk Access granted to Terminal.

Comment: @nohillside Agreed. It does work with FDA, so it's indeed a duplicate of the other question.